# Limited FaceBook friends show up in Contacts app in Mavericks or Yosemite

Tags: macos, contacts, calendar, facebook

I configured my Facebook account in OS X (both Mavericks & Yosemite) using following article >> http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18993

I have 200+ friends on FB, but on Contacts app it just shows 38. Remaining are missing, I don't know what I have done wrong.

Moreover, I have allowed events and birthday calendar to sync as well, but not all birthday events are showing up in OS X calendar app.

Help much appreciated. Thanks.

p.s. I followed following article ( http://www.scrubly.com/blog/how-to-mac/how-to-set-up-social-media-accounts-in-mavericks-and-why/ ) as well, but result is same. Not all FB friends show up.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that only the contacts that have provided useful contact information to Facebook are showing up in your OS X Contacts app. This article suggests that Facebook would be no longer adding contacts with no contact info to to your address book: [Facebook aims to declutter the iOS Contacts app by no longer syncing friends without useful contact info](http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/06/facebook-aims-to-declutter-the-ios-contacts-app-by-no-longer-syncing-friends-without-useful-contact-info/)